# can't get div IDs to disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery

New to Javascript, and this one is troubling me a little. I am basically trying to make a whack-a-mole type game. Once I add the images, I want to remove them one by one. I think I have the unique IDs added, but but when I add the image removal, everything stops working. What am I doing wrong? I also thought to find other items besides the .remove, but I'm not sure what that part of the code is called (method, function, etc.) My code is below.

```
        function addMole(){
        var xPos = randomPosX();
        var yPos = randomPosY();
        var count=0;
        $("#gamespace").append('<img src="img/roach.png" style="left: '+xPos+'px; top: '+yPos+'px;" id="img'+count+'"/>');
        var r=Math.floor(Math.random()*2000);
        t=setTimeout("addMole();", r);
        $("#gamespace").remove("img'+count+'"").removeAttribute(img'+count+'");
        count++;            
    }
```

Comment: Since addmole is a function... you can do... `setTimeout(addMole)` and I'd add 300 to your random number, so that it appears at least long enough to stay visible.

Answer (score 0):

You had some invalid quotations:

```
function addMole(){
    var xPos = randomPosX();
    var yPos = randomPosY();
    var count=0;
    $("#gamespace").append('<img src="img/roach.png" style="left: '+xPos+'px; top:' + yPos + 'px;" id="img'+count+'"/>');
    var r=Math.floor(Math.random()*2000);
    t = setTimeout(addMole, r);//is t defined already?
    $("#gamespace").remove("#img" + count).removeAttribute("img" + count);//why you need removeAttribute
    count++;            
}
```

Comment: @erkaner Yes, of course. And given the context of this function I do believe ``t`` might be defined somewhere else since it's not used inside this function.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts quick question: what if `addMole` has a parameter `addMole(a)`?

Comment: ``setTimeout(function(){addMole(a);}, r);``

Answer (score 0):

Everything stops working because this line is not valid JavaScript:

```
$("#gamespace").remove("img'+count+'"").removeAttribute(img'+count+'");
```

check your quotes: while `'...'` and `"..."` are interchangeable, single `"` and `'` are not.

Another problem is, after fixing the above, that your code logic doesn't pan out: you are adding an image then immediately removing it. I don't quite know what you are trying to do so I can't rewrite it for you; the best I can do is tell you to define your flow more in detail.

Finally, when you are creating elements programmatically, it is generally nicer and less failure-prone to keep element references rather than mess with IDs.

```
var $gamespace = $('#gamespace');
var $img = $('<img>').css({
  left: left,
  top: top
}).appendTo($gamespace);

// ...

$img.remove();
```

Comment: ...Or he could just switch the ``count++`` and ``$(...).remove(...)``?

Comment: wow. practically a double line within itself. i think i may have been looking at this long. i wanted to use id's because i want to do the add/remove to all the images, just not at the same time (randomly).

Comment: Then store references into an array, or something. Still less failure-prone. (As I said, I don't know the game you are doing.)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$("#gamespace").find("#img'"+count+"'").remove();
```

instead of

```
$("#gamespace").remove("img'+count+'"").removeAttribute(img'+count+'");
```

or.. while image ID is unique you can use directly

```
$("#img'"+count+"'").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

move the `count` declaration outside of your function... it's reset to `0` each time it runs.

Also, would add 300 to your random number for remove, so it will show at elast 1/3 second... beyond this, you can reference the function directly in the `setTimeout(addMole,r);` ... you're creating an extra wrapper that isn't needed.

```
var count = -1; //first is 1
function addMole(){
    count++;
    var rnd;
    var xPos = randomPosX();
    var yPos = randomPosY();
    var img = $('<img src="img/roach.png" />')
        .css({left:xPos,top:yPos})
        .addClass('mole')
        .attr('id','img'+count);
    img.click(addPoints);
    $('#gamespace').append(img);

    //remove image at random interval
    rnd = 300 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000);
    setTimeout(removeImageShim(img),rnd);

    //add next mole at random interval
    rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000);
    setTimeout(addMole, rnd);
}

function addPoints() {
    //TODO: addPoints
    $(this).remove();
}

function removeImageShim(img) {
    return function(){
      img.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not a wrapper, it's just pure eval ;)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I know this... in either case it creates an unnecessary reference and evaluated execution instead of just a reference to an existing method... either way the root of the problem is that `count` is declared inside the function.